# Как сделать чтоб при наведение другие элементы не двигались?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтоб при наведение другие элементы не двигались?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.th-panel-center {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /*background-color: rgba(17,17,17,0.8);*/
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.th-panel-date {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
}

.th-all-add-left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.th-panel:hover .th-all-add-left {
  border: 3px solid rgba(45, 78, 135, 0.8);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="th-panel">
  <div class="th-panel-center">
    <a class="uk-link-reset" href="#bets_one" uk-toggle>
      <div class="th-all-add-left">
        <div class="th-bs-one">
          <span class="uk-text-capitalize uk-text-bold">657</span><span class="th-rub uk-text-bold"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="th-under-bs-procent">
          65%
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="th-panel-date">
      26.02.2018 09:30
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` или изначально задать рамку, но прозрачную и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.th-panel-center {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /*background-color: rgba(17,17,17,0.8);*/
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}

.th-panel-date {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.th-all-add-left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.th-panel:hover .th-all-add-left {
  border-color: rgba(45, 78, 135, 0.8);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="th-panel">
  <div class="th-panel-center">
    <a class="uk-link-reset" href="#bets_one" uk-toggle>
      <div class="th-all-add-left">
        <div class="th-bs-one">
          <span class="uk-text-capitalize uk-text-bold">657</span><span class="th-rub uk-text-bold"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="th-under-bs-procent">
          65%
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="th-panel-date">
      26.02.2018 09:30
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```